# NWConnection sending multiple datagrams

Tags: ios, swift, network-programming

I'm trying to use the new `Network.framework` to send multiple datagrams at once.

In the WWDC 2018 talk 715 we see the following code sample:

```
// Hint that multiple datagrams should be sent as one batch
connection.batch {
     for datagram in datagramArray {
       connection.send(content: datagramArray, completion:.contentProcessed 
            { (error) in
               // Handle error in sending
       })
     }
}
```

However it seems counterintuitive that connection.send uses `datagramArray` as parameter and not `datagram`

The documentation of this framework is very scarce so I wonder if anyone know if the example above is right or I'm missing something.

Comment: That could be a typo in the WWDC presentation. The function [is documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwconnection/3003626-send)  and takes a `content: Data?` argument.

Comment: Yes, they confirmed it's a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just confirmed with an Apple Engineer that it was a typo.

So just for reference, in order to send multiple datagrams we shall use:

```
// Hint that multiple datagrams should be sent as one batch
connection.batch {
     for datagram in datagramArray {
       connection.send(content: datagram, completion:.contentProcessed 
            { (error) in
               // Handle error in sending
       })
     }
}
```